# How do I show multiple plots as separate figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create scatter plot with all the results
x = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,0]
y = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,1]

plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.ylabel("Verbal")
plt.xlabel("Quantitative")

plt.savefig("scores_plot.png")


# Create scatter plot of Quantitative Scores vs. Admissions
y_quant = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,0]
x_quant = np.loadtxt("admit_data.txt")[:]

plt.plot(x_quant, y_quant, "o")
plt.ylabel("Quantitative")
plt.xlabel("Admission")

plt.savefig("quant.png")

# Create scatter plot of Verbal Scores vs. Admissions
y_verb = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,1]
x_verb = np.loadtxt("admit_data.txt")[:]

plt.plot(x_verb, y_verb, "o")
plt.ylabel("Verbal")
plt.xlabel("Admission")

plt.savefig("verbal.png")
```

Where three figures are generated. However, when I try to run it and plot the three figures, they all get plotted to the same figure. For example, `quant.png` also has the data from the saved figure `scores_plot.png` and then the `verbal.png` has the data from the `scores_plot.png` and the `quant.png`. How can I get them to all save separately so I don't have to comment out the previous plots to generate each separately?

Answer (score 1):

If you define each as a separate figure using the `plt.figure()` command before each plot, they will not plot on top of each other. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create scatter plot with all the results
x = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,0]
y = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.ylabel("Verbal")
plt.xlabel("Quantitative")

plt.savefig("scores_plot.png")


# Create scatter plot of Quantitative Scores vs. Admissions
y_quant = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,0]
x_quant = np.loadtxt("admit_data.txt")[:]

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x_quant, y_quant, "o")
plt.ylabel("Quantitative")
plt.xlabel("Admission")

plt.savefig("quant.png")

# Create scatter plot of Verbal Scores vs. Admissions
y_verb = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,1]
x_verb = np.loadtxt("admit_data.txt")[:]

plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(x_verb, y_verb, "o")
plt.ylabel("Verbal")
plt.xlabel("Admission")

plt.savefig("verbal.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the pyplot interface for anything more than off-the-cuff interactive exploration.

Here's what I would do:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create scatter plot with all the results
x = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,0]
y = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,1]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, y, "o")
ax1.set_ylabel("Verbal")
ax2.set_xlabel("Quantitative")
fig1.savefig("scores_plot.png")


# Create scatter plot of Quantitative Scores vs. Admissions
y_quant = np.loadtxt("combined_data.txt")[:,0]
x_quant = np.loadtxt("admit_data.txt")[:]

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(x_quant, y_quant, "o")
ax2.set_ylabel("Quantitative")
ax2.set_xlabel("Admission")
fig2.savefig("quant.png")

# yada yada
```